# Small unit testing framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, reinventing-the-wheel, c++14

Here is a single-header small unit testing framework I wrote, that makes use of mostly preprocessor macros. I made it for knowing how unit testing works and, also, try to depend less of third-party libraries.

Code:

**utest.hpp**:

```
#ifndef CYNODELIC_UTEST_UTEST_HPP
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_UTEST_HPP

/* Usage:
 * 1. Initialize the test suite
 * 2. Add tests
 * 3. Initialize the running function
 * 4. Run
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Print file and line info (do nothing if CYNODELIC_UTEST_DO_NOT_PRINT_LINE_INFO was defined)
#ifndef CYNODELIC_UTEST_DO_NOT_PRINT_LINE_INFO
    #define CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT std::cout << "         File: " << __FILE__ << " on line " << __LINE__ << "\n";
#else
    #define CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT
#endif

// Initialize test suite
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_INITIALIZE_TEST_SUITE(name) \
namespace utest_suite_##name##_ \
{                               \
    std::vector<cynodelic::utest::test_cont>   test_list; \
    std::vector<cynodelic::utest::test_status> stats;     \
}                               \

// Checking
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(cnd) \
do \
{  \
    if (!(cnd))                             \
    {                                       \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_red("[FAILED] ")   << #cnd << "\n"; \
        CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT;                                                  \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::FAIL);                           \
    }    \
    else \
    {    \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_green("[ PASS ] ") << #cnd << "\n"; \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS);                           \
    }    \
} while (false) \

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FALSE(cnd) CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(!(cnd))

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_OPERATOR(op,a,b) \
do \
{  \
    if (!((a) op (b))) \
    {                  \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_red("[FAILED] ")   << #a << " " << #op << " " << #b << "\n"; \
        CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT;                                                                           \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::FAIL);                                                    \
    }    \
    else \
    {    \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_green("[ PASS ] ") << #a << " " << #op << " " << #b << "\n"; \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS);                                                    \
    }    \
} while (false) \

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(val_a,val_b)       CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_OPERATOR(==,val_a,val_b)
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_NON_EQUALS(val_a,val_b)   CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_OPERATOR(!=,val_a,val_b)
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_GREATER_THAN(val_a,val_b) CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_OPERATOR(>,val_a,val_b)
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_LESSER_THAN(val_a,val_b)  CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_OPERATOR(<,val_a,val_b)

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(a,b)       \
do \
{  \
    if (!(cynodelic::utest::internal::almost_equals(a,b))) \
    {                                                      \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_red("[FAILED] ")   << #a << " == " << #b << "\n"; \
        CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT;                                                                \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::FAIL);                                         \
    }    \
    else \
    {    \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_green("[ PASS ] ") << #a << " == " << #b << "\n"; \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS);                                         \
    }    \
} while (false) \

// Assertion
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_TRUE(cnd) \
do \
{  \
    if (!(cnd))                              \
    {                                        \
        std::cerr << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_red("[FAILED] ")   << #cnd << "\n"; \
        CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT;                                                  \
        std::cout << "\n" << stats.size() << " tests have been passed.\n";              \
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                        \
    }    \
    else \
    {    \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_green("[ PASS ] ") << #cnd << "\n"; \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS);                           \
    }    \
} while (false) \

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_FALSE(cnd) CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_TRUE(!(cnd))

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_OPERATOR(op,a,b)                                      \
do \
{  \
    if (!((a) op (b)))                                                                   \
    {                                                                                    \
        std::cerr << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_red("[FAILED] ")   << #a << " " << #op << " " << #b << "\n"; \
        CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT;                                                                           \
        std::cout << "\n" << stats.size() << " tests have been passed.\n";                                       \
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                 \
    }    \
    else \
    {    \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_green("[ PASS ] ") << #a << " " << #op << " " << #b << "\n"; \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS);                                                    \
    }    \
} while (false) \

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_EQUALS(val_a,val_b)       CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_OPERATOR(==,val_a,val_b)
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_NON_EQUALS(val_a,val_b)   CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_OPERATOR(!=,val_a,val_b)
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_GREATER_THAN(val_a,val_b) CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_OPERATOR(>,val_a,val_b)
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_LESSER_THAN(val_a,val_b)  CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_OPERATOR(<,val_a,val_b)

#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ASSERT_FLOAT_EQUALS(a,b)      \
do \
{  \
    if (!(cynodelic::utest::internal::almost_equals(a,b))) \
    {                                                      \
        std::cerr << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_red("[FAILED] ")   << #a << " == " << #b << "\n"; \
        CYNODELIC_UTEST_FILE_LINE_OUT;                                                                \
        std::cout << "\n" << stats.size() << " tests have been passed.\n";                            \
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                      \
    }    \
    else \
    {    \
        std::cout << cynodelic::utest::internal::co_green("[ PASS ] ") << #a << " == " << #b << "\n"; \
        stats.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS);                                         \
    }    \
} while (false) \

// Add a test
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(name,method) \
namespace utest_suite_##name##_               \
{                                             \
    struct utest_##name##_method_##method##_holder \
    {  \
        utest_##name##_method_##method##_holder() \
        { \
            test_list.push_back(cynodelic::utest::test_cont( #name , #method ,&test_fun)); \
        } \
        static void test_fun(); \
    }; \
}          \
utest_suite_##name##_::utest_##name##_method_##method##_holder utest_##name##_method_##method; \
void utest_suite_##name##_::utest_##name##_method_##method##_holder::test_fun()                \

// Initialize the running function
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_INITIALIZE_RUNNING(name) \
namespace utest_suite_##name##_                  \
{                                                \
    bool run_tests() \
    {                \
        std::cout << "==================== Test suite: " << #name << " ====================\n\n"; \
                                                     \
        for (std::size_t i=0;i<test_list.size();i++) \
        {                                            \
            std::cout << "Running " << test_list[i].test_method              \
                      << " test from " << test_list[i].test_name << "...\n"; \
            test_list[i]();                                                  \
            std::cout << "\n";                                               \
        }                                        \
                                                 \
        std::size_t passed_tests = 0;            \
        for (std::size_t i=0;i<stats.size();i++) \
            if (stats[i] == cynodelic::utest::test_status::PASS) \
                passed_tests++;                              \
                                                 \
        std::cout << passed_tests << " out of " << stats.size() << " tests have been passed.\n\n"; \
                                                 \
        if (passed_tests != stats.size()) \
            return false;             \
        return true; \
    } \
} \

// Run the tests
#define CYNODELIC_UTEST_RUN_TEST_SUITE(name) utest_suite_##name##_::run_tests()

namespace cynodelic { namespace utest {

namespace internal
{

// Check equality with double
template <typename FloatTypeA,typename FloatTypeB>
inline typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_arithmetic<FloatTypeA>::value && std::is_arithmetic<FloatTypeB>::value,
        bool
    >::type almost_equals(const FloatTypeA& a,const FloatTypeB& b)
{
    double a_ = static_cast<double>(a);
    double b_ = static_cast<double>(b);
    return std::fabs(a_-b_) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() || std::fabs(a_-b_) < std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
}

// Colorize output (if CYNODELIC_UTEST_NON_COLORIZED_OUTPUT is not defined)
#ifndef CYNODELIC_UTEST_NON_COLORIZED_OUTPUT
inline std::string co_red(const char *x)   { return std::string("\033[1;31m")+std::string(x)+std::string("\033[0m"); }
inline std::string co_green(const char *x) { return std::string("\033[1;32m")+std::string(x)+std::string("\033[0m"); }
#else
inline std::string co_red(const char *x)   { return std::string(x); }
inline std::string co_green(const char *x) { return std::string(x); }
#endif

} // end of "internal" namespace

// Test status enum (this is used instead of bool)
enum class test_status : std::uint8_t
{
    FAIL = 0xe0,
    PASS = 0xe1
};

// Test container
struct test_cont
{
    std::string test_name;      // Test name
    std::string test_method;    // Test method name
    std::function<void()> tmet; // The test method

    test_cont(const char *name,const char *method,void(*tm_ptr)()) :
        test_name(name),
        test_method(method),
        tmet(tm_ptr) {}

    // Run the test contained
    void operator()()
    {
        tmet();
    }
};

}} // end of "cynodelic::utest" namespace

#endif
```

**utest_demo.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>

#include "utest.hpp"

// This class was made for demonstration
class vec3
{
    public:
        double x, y, z;
        vec3() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
        vec3(double x,double y,double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

        vec3(const vec3& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z) {}

        vec3& operator=(const vec3& other)
        {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
            z = other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        void swap(vec3& other)
        {
            std::swap(x,other.x);
            std::swap(y,other.y);
            std::swap(z,other.z);
        }

        friend void swap(vec3& lhs,vec3& rhs)
        {
            lhs.swap(rhs);
        }

        friend bool operator==(const vec3& lhs,const vec3& rhs)
        {
            return (lhs.x == rhs.x)&&(lhs.y == rhs.y)&&(lhs.z == rhs.z);
        }

        friend bool operator!=(const vec3& lhs,const vec3& rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }

        vec3& operator+=(const vec3& other)
        {
            x += other.x;
            y += other.y;
            z += other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        friend vec3 operator+(vec3 lhs,const vec3& rhs)
        {
            lhs += rhs;
            return lhs;
        }

        vec3& operator-=(const vec3& other)
        {
            x -= other.x;
            y -= other.y;
            z -= other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        friend vec3 operator-(vec3 lhs,const vec3& rhs)
        {
            lhs -= rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
};

CYNODELIC_UTEST_INITIALIZE_TEST_SUITE(vec3);

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,copy_construction)
{
    vec3 t1(0.5,0.25,0.125);
    vec3 t2(t1);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1,t2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.x,t2.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.y,t2.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.z,t2.z);
}

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,assignment)
{
    vec3 t1(1,2,3);
    vec3 t2(0.1,0,-0.1);
    t1 = t2;
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1,t2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.x,t2.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.y,t2.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.z,t2.z);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.x,0.1);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.y,0);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(t1.z,-0.1);
}

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,equality)
{
    vec3 v1(1.111,2.345,3.0005);
    vec3 v2(1.111,2.345,3.0005);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1 == v2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1.x == v2.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1.y == v2.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1.z == v2.z);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_NON_EQUALS(v1,v2);
}

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,inequality)
{
    vec3 v1(0.01,0.1,1);
    vec3 v2(2,4,8);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1 != v2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1.x != v2.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1.y != v2.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_TRUE(v1.z != v2.z);
}

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,swapping)
{
    vec3 v1(-1.1,-1.2,2.1);
    vec3 v2(14.32,23.14,32.41);
    swap(v1,v2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v1.x,14.32);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v1.y,23.14);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v1.z,32.41);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v2.x,-1.1);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v2.y,-1.2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v2.z,2.1);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_NON_EQUALS(v1,v2);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_NON_EQUALS(v1.x,v2.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_NON_EQUALS(v1.y,v2.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_NON_EQUALS(v1.z,v2.z);
}

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,addition)
{
    vec3 v1(1,2,3);
    vec3 v2(5,6,7);
    vec3 res = v1+v2;
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v1+v2,res);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.x+v2.x,res.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.y+v2.y,res.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.z+v2.z,res.z);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.x+v2.x,6);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.y+v2.y,8);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.z+v2.z,10);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(res.x,6);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(res.y,8);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(res.z,10);
}

CYNODELIC_UTEST_ADD_TEST(vec3,substraction)
{
    vec3 v1(1.25,0.75,4.101001);
    vec3 v2(0.5 ,2.25,4);
    vec3 res = v1-v2;
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_EQUALS(v1-v2,res);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.x-v2.x,res.x);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.y-v2.y,res.y);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.z-v2.z,res.z);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.x-v2.x,0.75);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.y-v2.y,-1.5);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(v1.z-v2.z,0.101001);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(res.x,0.75);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(res.y,-1.5);
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_CHECK_FLOAT_EQUALS(res.z,0.101001);
}

// Initialize the test suite running function
CYNODELIC_UTEST_INITIALIZE_RUNNING(vec3);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    // Check if all the tests passed or failed
    bool test_res = CYNODELIC_UTEST_RUN_TEST_SUITE(vec3);

    if (!test_res)
        std::cout << "Test has been failed.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Test finished successfully.\n";
}
```

Any suggestions, improvements, etc. are welcome, especially regarding its design.

Comment: I did something similar a while ago http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69061/minimal-c-unit-test-framework?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are great (as is testing).

When one of the test indicates a failure in the test it may take a while to find the actual problem. As a result you may want to re-run a specific test (or set of tests) without running all the tests (as all the test could take 30 minutes).

As a result I would expect to be able to pass it run time arguments on the command line to specify which tests I want to run (if no arguments are passed then run all the tests).

If you run unit tests in isolation you need a way to make sure that the environment is setup correctly (as some tests may change the global state). As a result most testing frameworks provide a `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods  on each class. These are called before and after (respectively) each test.

Why does `CYNODELIC_UTEST_RUN_TEST_SUITE()` need to know the name of the test. This should run all test suites. Otherwise you open yourself to accidently leaving out test suites.

Personally I would pass the command line arguments to this macro.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CYNODELIC_UTEST_RUN_TEST_SUITE(argc, argv);
}
```